# Is it possible to auto subscribe in sites through a Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, css

I have built a site and have several social networks to promote it, and sometimes I have giveways to people which I normally have through facebook. The giveaways normally require that the person subscribe to something (as a counterpart of receiving the giveaway or participating on trying to win it), but facebook and other sites just are bad for these kind of things, specially proving that you subscribed to anything.

So here's my thought:

- Use a fillout template (like a HTML FORM)
- person login with a FACEBOOK Account
- Based on that Facebook account, person subscribes to
  newsletter, likes a page, whatever, but everything done through that
  FORM-like thing, logged in, one step to participate.

In your experience, is this even possible? with what? CSS, HTML, JSQUERY...
This time I'm opened to anything you can guide me, I'm tired of trying to work
giveways through social networking site's GUIs is just annoying...

Thanks for all the help you can provide.

Alban

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want [Oauth](http://oauth.net/) and [OpenId](http://openid.net/). It's not particularly easy to set up, but it's very effective. If you sign into stackoverflow using google you're probably using it.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) facebook no longer support it, using facebook connect instead, but almost everything else does.

Comment: yeah what I thought, seemed like the doors were closed all around :S ah well back to the drawing board...